# Unable to load .csv data from hdfs into Hive table in Hadoop

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to load csv files into a Hive table.  I need to have it done through HDFS.

My end goal is to have the hive table also connected to Impala tables, which I can then load into Power BI, but I am having trouble getting the Hive tables to populate.

I create a table in the Hive query editor using the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbname.table_name (
    time_stamp TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'time_stamp',
    attribute STRING COMMENT 'attribute',
    value DOUBLE COMMENT 'value',
    vehicle STRING COMMENT 'vehicle',
    filename STRING COMMENT 'filename')
```

Then I check and see the LOCATION using the following code:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE dbname.table_name;
```

and find that is has gone to the default location:
hdfs://our_company/user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/table_name

So I go to the above location in HDFS, and I upload a few csv files manually, which are in the same five-column format as the table I created.  Here is where I expect this data to be loaded into the Hive table, but when I go back to dbname in Hive, and open up the table I made, all values are still null, and when I try to open in browser I get:

DB Error
AnalysisException: Could not resolve path: 'dbname.table_name'

Then I try the following code:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://our_company/user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/table_name' INTO TABLE dbname.table_name;
```

It runs fine, but the table in Hive still does not populate.

I also tried all of the above using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE instead, and specifying the HDFS in the LOCATION argument.  I also tried making an HDFS location first, uploading the csv files, then CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE with the LOCATION argument pointed at the pre-made HDFS location.

I already made sure I have authorization privileges.

My table will not populate with the csv files, no matter which method I try.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbname.table_name (
    time_stamp STRING COMMENT 'time_stamp', 
    attribute STRING COMMENT 'attribute', 
    value STRING COMMENT 'value', 
    vehicle STRING COMMENT 'vehicle', 
    filename STRING COMMENT 'filename') 
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

and

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs://our_company/user/hive/warehouse/dbname.db/table_name' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE dbname.table_name;
```